# ALter view after insert by trigger sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I create a - view in sql server.
I want to alter the view every time that a - row is added to my table .
I create trigger for it :

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger1
ON dbo.Table1
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
ALTER VIEW VIEW1 as
SELECT *
From Table1
END
```

But I get the error : 'ALTER VIEW' must be the only statement in the batch.

What should I do to correct it error ?

Comment: If you could explain in *what way* you want to alter the view, we may understand better what you're attempting to achieve. As it is, as marc says, this doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WHY** do you want to alter your view every time a row is inserted? That doesn't make **any sense** at all!

The view doesn't **contain** (or store) the rows it shows - it's just a **stored query**...

It will always go to the base table and fetch the data again, when you select from it. There's really **no need** to constantly alter the view!

It will show that row after it's been inserted *without* being altered...